# Insert links into div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert some links into a div using jQuery. My jQuery so far inserts the out structure onto another selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selector = ('.copy p');
  var div = ('<div class="links"><div class="i-links">Links</div></div>');


  // Check if selector is present 

  if (selector.length > 1) {
    $(div).appendTo(selector);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-links">
  <div class="seo-links">
    <a href="Url">Link1</a>
    <a href="Url">Link1</a>
    <a href="Url">Link1</a>
    <a href="Url">Link1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it better to define the link structure i.e Link1 as an array or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Take links as an array, loop on it and keep appending the links onto required element.

Comment: selector = ('.copy p'); should be ar selector = $('.copy p'); same for div

Comment: try to use _each()_ with jquery

Comment: @Sfili_81 why?  https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/ *"If there is more than one target element..."*

Comment: TBH, your question is very unclear.  You have some HTML, but your code doesn't match the HTML.  What's the "out structure"?  Did you mean to leave off the `$` from `$(selector)`? If not, why is it in brackets and not just text `var selector = ".copy p"`?  Do you have more than one `.copy p`?  Is it just trying to take a single copy?  or reproduce multiple times?

Comment: If he want to iterate an copy any single link and not the entire block, but probably i misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Sfili_81 ah - you mean the each the source, not the target - that makes more sense and might be appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sorry I should be more precise on my comment